# Creating a plist in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plist

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to learn it using Rails 3 (RC).

I have managed to use http://plist.rubyforge.org/ for supporting the output of plists. I would like to check with you guys to see if my approach is the right way to do it. Here goes:

1. In the gemfile I added `gem 'plist'`
2. In config/initializers/mime_types.rb I added `Mime::Type.register "application/plist", :plist`
3. In the controller, I added `format.plist { render :plist => @product }` in `show`
4. In the model, I added
   `def to_plist

     attributes.to_plist

   end`
5. And finally, in the view file show.plist.erb, I have `<%= raw @product.to_plist %>`

Accessing for instance /products/2.plist works fine, but being new to Rails, I'm wondering if there are anything I should have done differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks right to me.

Answer (score 2):

The only suggestion I have is to perhaps mix in the `to_plist` method into `ActiveRecord::Base` so that you don't have to define it over and over in each model.  Perhaps this method will even support `render_with` syntax?

I'm about to do something similar myself.